# Is non-existence of critical point too strong to imply all trajectories of gradient descent convergence to only one local min?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, optimization

Consider $f(x)$ to be a smooth function defined on an open set in $R^n$, for example, $(a,b)^n$. Assume $(0,..,0)$ is a local minimum of $f(x)$ in $(a,b)^n$.

I am reading a paper that there is a theorem which imposes constraints in order to guarantee that in $(a,b)^n$, there is no other local minimum except for $(0,...,0)$. The true goal is to guarantee that trajectory starting from any point in $(a,b)$ except for $(0,\cdots,0)$ will converge to $(0,\cdots,0)$.

The constraint they imposed is: there is no other critical point in $(a,b)^n$, except for $(0,...,0)$.

I am confused on: **whether this constraint is too strong**? in the sense that:

if there is no other critical point, then there is no other local minimum except for $(0,...,0)$.

Conversely, if there is no other local mimum, then we cannot say there is no other critical point, since we can still have local maximum and saddles.

Comment: Correct.  The given sufficient condition is not necessary.

Comment: @GEdgar If our goal is not just guarantee $(0,\cdots,0)$ is the local minimum, but also that, the trajectory of gradient descent starting from $\forall x\in(a,b)^n$ will converge to $(0,\cdots,0)$. Then we would need to impose the constraint that (1) $(0,\cdots,0)$ is the only local min, and (2) there is no local max. Is this correct?

Comment: Consider two cases: (1) in the closed interval $[a,b]^n$, if $(0,\cdots,0)$ is the only local min in $[a,b]^n$, then there is no chance to have local max in $(a,b)^n$ (indeed, if there is one local max in the open interval $(a,b)^n$, then this will lead to the existence of two local min in $[a,b]^n$, and at least one of them is not $(0,\cdots,0)$. If it is in the interior (i.e. $(a,b)^n$) or it is in the border of $[a,b]^n$, then we will have two local min in $[a,b]^n$, which contradicts the assumption ($(0,\cdots,0)$ is the only local min in $[a,b]^n$).

Comment: Thus, imposing $(0,\cdots,0) \textit{ is the only local min in } [a,b]^n$ is enough to guarantee that all trajectories will converge to $(0,\cdots,0)$.

Comment: @GEdgar (2) Assume $(0,\cdots,0)$ is the local min in the open interval $(a,b)^n$, then if there exists a local max in $(a,b)^n$ will lead to at least one local min in the border, that will cause trajectoties may not all converge to $(0,\cdots,0)$ but converge to this local min in the boarder. Thus, in this case imposing the assumption ($(0,\cdots,0)$ is the local min in the open interval $(a,b)^n$) is not enough to guarantee that all trajectories converge to $(0,\cdots,0)$. Thus we need to impose: there is no other critical point.

Comment: As I read the claim as you describe it, it is only that having no other critical points will guarantee $\mathbf 0$ is the only local minimum. This is true. They may have a goal of showing all trajectories lead to $\bf 0$, but they have not arrived at that goal with just this claim. They will need to add more constraints on $f$ to ensure that trajectories do not leave $(a,b)^n$. Requiring no other critical points (thus ensuring no local maxima or saddle points) is not sufficient to prevent such trajectories.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Could you provide related materials on this claim (e.g. 'no other critical points' is not sufficient to guarantee the trajectories converge to the local minimum.) ? I think problems like this is easily for me to make mistake. If there would be formal description, that will be very nice!

Comment: Consider a surface that rises up on the outside to a circular rim, then drops down to a depression in the middle. Now slant that rim so that one side is higher than its opposite, but the depression is still lower than any point on the rim. Choose your domain rectangle to not include the lowest or highest points of the rim, but extend out beyond the rim in the other direction (if you insist the domain be square, stretch the surface so the high and low rim points are outside it). Trajectories starting outside the rim will exit the domain instead of going to the minimum in the bowl.